# How to minimize PyBitmessage to the system tray?

Tags: python, qt, system-tray, pyqt, qsystemtrayicon

I recently installed PyBitMessage, and now I can't get it to minimize to the system tray. If I click the red X, it just exits (unlike Transmission, which can be configured to "survive" being closed - the red X can be made to simply hide the GUI.)

I was wondering, is there a way to replicate this behavior in Bitmessage, or de we have to wait for the developer to write this behavior into the program? Is there something I can do to Ubuntu itself to hide the GUI?
Right now, I have rigged up a solution where it lives in Workspace 4 most of the time; I just switch to that workspace whenever I need to use the program. I'd like something a little more "professional", though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can click the application indicator of PyBitmessage and will see an option to show/hide the application:

[image]

Closing the window by clicking on the red X will always quit PyBitmessage. If you think PyBitmessage should behave differently, you should [open a bug report](https://github.com/Bitmessage/PyBitmessage/issues/new) in the bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I must have been doing something wrong; I didn't think to check the taskbar icon itself -_-